# link_to in ruby on rails with additional html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know there are more of these, but I couldn't find my answer as I'm still fairly new to RoR.

I need to take this:

```
<% if params[:forum_id] %>
    <%= link_to "#{category.name}", category_path(category.id,:forum_id => params[:forum_id]) %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "#{category.name}", category_path(category.id) %>
<% end %>
```

which prints out:

```
<a href="mylink....">name</a>
```

and I need:

```
<a href="mylink....">
    <figure></figure>
    <span>name</span>
</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `link_to` as a block:

```
<%= link_to category_path(category_id) do %>
  <figure></figure>
  <span><%= category.name %></span>
<% end %>
```

EDIT

The full solution:

```
<% if params[:forum_id] %>
  <%= link_to category_path(category.id,:forum_id => params[:forum_id]) do %>
    <figure></figure>
    <span><%= category.name %></span>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to category_path(category.id) do %>
    <figure></figure>
    <span><%= category.name %></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Just replace the first line by: `<%= link_to category_path(category.id,:forum_id => params[:forum_id]) do %>`

Comment: Another option would be calling a helper method that returns the HTML portion of the link.